# command not found: django-admin when using django-admin startproject prj in mac

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to start a new project using django usign the command

```
django-admin startproject prj1
```

in Mac, but it shows command not found:django-admin.

Comment: Did you install the Django (`pip install Django`)?

Comment: I did
 pip install --user django==1.9.10

Comment: Yes, it did work and created a new dir with manage.py and some other python files. Could you just explain why did this code worked and the other didn't

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The `--user` option  conveniently installs packages without requiring admin access, in a place where Python will also look when importing modules. On MacOS, the installation location is in `/Users/<username>/Library/Python/<x.y>/lib/python/site-packages/` (with `<x.y>` indicating the Python version, such as 2.7, which is still the default Python version on MacOS). For other OSes, this will be a different location. In any case, users do not have to bother with this information, because the import location is, as mentioned, automatically searched: there is no need to add this location to the environment variable (envvar) `PYTHONPATH`.

Perhaps somewhat unfortunately, this is not the case for executables that are installed together with packages, such as `django-admin`. The reason is that this "user-installed package & executable" is not standardized across all types of software; it's just something that Python, and perhaps a few other types of software, use. Therefore, one manually has to add the corresponding path to the environment variable `PATH`, which is the envvar that defines in which locations executables are searched for. The path where executables are installed is slightly different than the above path: `/Users/<username>/Library/Python/<x.y>/bin/`.

Thus, one has to set the `PATH` envvar to *add* (most of the time, add the front of it), and to make it more permanent, "export" the variable (in bash or zsh shell). Thus:

```
export PATH=/Users/<username>/Library/Python/<x.y>/bin/:$PATH
```

To make this more permanent, so that it works each one starts up a new terminal, add the above to your `/Users/<username>/.bashrc` file, at the end. Then, this is set each time you open a new terminal.

---

Finally, many packages that also install executables also have the option to run as an executable module. This requires running `python` with the `-m` option, followed by the package name, and in this case, followed again by the relevant command and argument.

Thus the following also (always) works, without having to extend `PATH` as above:

```
python -m django startproject prj1
```

The latter is also convenient if you install a new Python version in an awkward location (e.g., Python 3.7 in /opt/local or something), and use an alias instead of setting `PATH` (I often use e.g. `alias py37=/opt/local/bin/python3.7`). And then use `python3.7 -m <package> ...` as above. This, however, is just what preferences people have: other people just want to be able to simply type `django-admin` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

First Activate the virtual environment ..type in

```
......source your_env/bin/activate
```

Then immediatly run the create project command.Note now you will be in the venv created above your_env...

```
......django-admin startproject prji
```